# Is there a way to assign a List to a field?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I know the question seems weird but hear me out...

Say I have a group of users called Managers.

List userList = [Manager1, Manager2,Manager3,...,ManagerN]

And I wanted to assign one of these managers to a record using a round robin which uses a modulus to determine the count.

```
integer count = 0;    
integer userModulus = Math.round(Math.mod(Count, userList.size()));
count++;
```

Then use this value to return the index of the list like userList[userModulus] right?

Originally I planned to use custom metadata types to house the lists with the intent of managing these custom metadata lists by screen flow... but on implementation I don't see this being realistic.

Is there a way to store this list of users in a field, or some other kind of structure where it can be maintained by managers or other non-admin users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are code-free ways to do it, see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.essentials_round_robin_lead_assignment.htm&type=5

Or ready pieces of code you can get inspired with: https://gist.github.com/eskfung/f342b47ecc0849deb0cb

Many ways to achieve this. You could have a field on the User (picklist? checkbox? being assigned a special Role?) and then

```
List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Name 
    FROM User 
    WHERE IsActive = true AND UserRole.Name = 'Sales Manager'
    ORDER BY Name];
```

Bit crude but should get the job done.

You could also add them to a public group or queue? Queues should be pretty close to normal owner assignment functionality anyway. And then you'd query all group/queue members. Queues are a type of group so it'd sit in same table: [Group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_group.htm), [GroupMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm)

```
SELECT Id, Name, Type
FROM Group
WHERE Type IN ('Regular', 'Queue')

SELECT Id, Name
FROM User
WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.Name = 'MyGroup' AND Group.Type = 'Regular')
```

It's bit simple, it assumes people are directly assigned to the group.  In reality groups/queues often consist of other groups, roles, roles+subordinates, not just manually assigned individuals... You'd need to keep querying the GroupMember records till you exhaust the tree.

Still, should be enough to get you started?

Comment: This answer is great and satisfies my question. One small follow-up not mentioned in the question... this particular object I'm working on has an issue with SOQL queries. Is there a way to do this without using a query or would it be necessary for this use case?

Comment: You mean triggers have poor performance and "too many soql: 101"? It could be just 1 query but if that's unacceptable (and code-free is not an option like that help article or a flow) - maybe look into custom settings? Fetching them doesn't count as query. Or if assignments don't change often - experiment with Platform Cache? Up to 48h caching?